# how can I make a trigger at posedge and negede of a sine wave

Tags: verilog

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module trigger(
    input signed [15:0] Interf_cut_scaled,
    output reg trigger
);

reg [15:0] prev_value;

always @(*) begin
    prev_value <= Interf_cut_scaled;

    if ((Interf_cut_scaled > 0 && prev_value <= 0) || (Interf_cut_scaled < 0 && prev_value >= 0))
        trigger <= 1'b1; // Positive or negative sign change
    else if ((Interf_cut_scaled > 0 && prev_value > 0) || (Interf_cut_scaled < 0 && prev_value < 0))
        trigger <= 1'b0; // No sign change
    else
        trigger <= 1'b0; // Zero crossing
end

endmodule
```

I want to have a trigger when I have a sign change

Comment: What's the problem with what you have now? Did you mean to use a clock signal?

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. The code needs a clocked process to infer registers and establish the previous and current versions of the Interf_cut_scaled sample.
2. The Interf_cut_scaled sample needs to be declared as signed to check less than 0. The default of a `reg` variable is unsigned.

Made those changes and simpified the logic.  Added a default value to the sample for illustrative purposes in simulation.  You may or may not need a reset to set an initial value depending on your application.

These changes produces a 1-clock wide trigger_out pulse after the 0  sample on the minus to plus or plus to minus transition.

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module trigger(
    input clk,
    input signed [15:0] Interf_cut_scaled,
    output reg trigger_out
);

  reg signed [15:0] Interf_cut_scaled_prev = -3;

  // change to clocked always block
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    Interf_cut_scaled_prev <= Interf_cut_scaled;
    
    if( (Interf_cut_scaled_prev < 0) && (! (Interf_cut_scaled < 0) ) )
      trigger_out <= 1'b1;
    else
      if( (Interf_cut_scaled_prev > 0) & (! (Interf_cut_scaled > 0) ) )
        trigger_out <= 1'b1;
     else
       trigger_out <= 1'b0;
    
  end
  
endmodule
```

In the waves shown, a stimulus is applied starting at -2 then counts going toward 0, goes positive and swings back negative to demonstrate both transitions.

Waves:
[image]